# Lag in Data Returned

Tags: channel-entries, templates, database, optimization

I have a pretty simple template set up that has one image and a block of text, but for some reason the page takes 3 seconds to load at 37 queries. I have tag caching set so subsequent loads of the page are around 2 seconds at 21 queries. What's causing this lag in data being returned? The image that's being called is on Rackspace Cloud Files CDN and only 140kb in size. Here's the applicable chunk of info from Template Debugging:

(0.026589 / 11.08MB) -> Method Called: entries

(1.552342 / 19.17MB) -> Data Returned

Related to this is the homepage which takes 90.5082 seconds to load at 103 queries on first load. Though this is probably due to the fact I'm calling 100 images with Channel Images :)

Any thoughts on how to optimize? The caching works great, but it's the initial load that I'm worried about.

Comment: Can u use the browser tools to see how long each query is taking (CSS, HTML, js, images etc). The actual usage is quite light I'd like to see how long the files that make up the page take to load.

Comment: What host are you using?

Comment: Rackspace is hosting the production site, but this is also happening on my local environment.